# Copy values to empty cells on the right

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for something like copying values to empty cells below from ASAP Utilities but instead copying towards right. So, when I select a row it will copy values from filled cell towards empty cells on the right until there's a filled cell and then it will start copying that one and so on.

Here an example of code that works except when I select an entire row:

```
Sub CopyToRight()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"

Exit_This_Sub:
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
Resume Exit_This_Sub

End Sub
```

[Example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buqdkcv5eau8nag/examplefile.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195728%28v=office.11%29.aspx `Range.FillRight` is going to be your best bet.

Comment: Do you need this to loop through all rows?  Please post an example of your sheet.

Comment: Added code to illustrate. I do not need this to loop. Just to be able to select any row I'm interested in.

Comment: Do you want to just do one row at a time? Will you run this on a particular row?  Do you want to loop through all rows?

Comment: Just the row I'm selecting, not a particular one.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
Sub CopyToRight()

Dim CurCol As Long, CurRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

CurRow = ActiveCell.Row

LastCol = Cells(CurRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For CurCol = 1 To LastCol
    If Not Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = "" Then
        Set CopyRng = Cells(CurRow, CurCol)
    ElseIf CopyRng is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error First Cell is Blank"
    Else
        Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Text = CopyRng.Text
    End If
Next CurCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it displays a Type mismatch error for line     If Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = "" Then. Must be because I'm selecting text.

Comment: I tested this working on a simple A-blank-blank-blank-B-blank-blank-C-blank-D row and it copied across just fine.

Comment: Please share some example data for one of your rows so I can test and try to replicate the error.

Comment: It's just plain text that fails. It works with numeric values though.

Comment: Change all the `.Value` to `.Text` and try again

Comment: Now it displays 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error. Yesterday was working :\

Comment: Of course I'll do :). Now says 'Unable to set the property of text class'

Comment: Edit your initial post with a dummy row of data (include where you have blanks) so that I can test and try to replicate error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, I've been very busy, plus Christmas... I've just uploaded an example file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this? Without any code example it's hard to see what you are trying to do.

```
Sub CopyRow()
    Rows("32:32").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("33:33").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I pasted it the code, so you can try selecting some cells in a row. I want this to work selecting the entire row.